# Update file using c

Tags: c++, c

I am using fprintf command for writing on the text file, but every time when the function called its remove the previous data, I actually want to update the file so that the previous data remain. Kindly guide me how I can make it possible?

Comment: C++ is not C. Don't tag C questions with C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you open the file use "a" for append.

```
FILE * file = fopen("filename", "a");
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to insert data "in the middle" of an existing file (nor at the start): data can be appended (put after what used to be the end of the file) or it can overwrite existing data. This is not an issue with C nor with C++ in particular: it's language-independent and connected only to how computer filesystems work.

To "make believe" you're inserting data in the middle, you have to make a new file, copy all the data that goes "before" your new data from the old file to the new one, then add your new data, and finally copy all the data that goes "after" your new data.  Note that this way you're always writing to the *end* of the new file, i.e, appending.

When that's done, you can close the new file, remove the old one, and rename the new one to the name that the old one used to have ("rename replacing" can be an atomic operation in some cases, depending on your OS and filesystem, and if that's feasible this would be better).

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in append mode instead:

```
f = fopen("logfile.txt", "a");
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in append mode as follows

Append to a file. Writing operations append data at the end of the file. The file is created if it does not exist.

```
f = fopen("filename", "a");
```

or

```
f = fopen("filename", "a+");
```

Opens a file for reading and appending. All writing operations are performed at the end of the file, protecting the previous content to be overwritten. You can reposition (fseek, rewind) the internal pointer to anywhere in the file for reading, but writing operations will move it back to the end of file. The file is created if it does not exist.